# Using typescript import/export without requireJS or systemJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

I'm migrating a large angular 1.5 application from JS to TS 1.8, one component at a time. I'd like to use file modules but i don't want to use requireJS/SystemJS. Is there a way to synchronously load all JS files with `script` tags, and still use typescripts `import/export`?

Or if this isn't possible, is there a way to shared classes and controllers across multiple files with TS?

Comment: There's no builtin mechanism for this in typescript as ts is just language and not a framework. If you want to do that then you'll need to either implement that yourself or use an existing library (if one exists), but I strongly recommend to use a module system such as SystemJS and amd as they will save you a lot of time and headaches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Namespaces](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces.html) and some kind of import. You can use the import syntax to declare the name of the class or namespace you import in your file. With this way you can also simply use the typescript modules simply by addressing the classes or functions with namespace as prefix.